# Code Coverage not showing coverage in source dlls, only showing coverage in test dlls

Tags: performance, visual-studio-2012, code-coverage, performance-monitor

The code coverage is only displaying coverage of test dll. I want the coverage of the source dlls in the service which I am testing.

Followed the below steps:
1. Instrumented binaries:
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Team Tools\Performance Tools\x64\vsinstr.exe" %%f /COVERAGE

ALL THE BINARIES WERE INSTRUMENTED.

2. Stared Perf Monitor
   "c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Team Tools\Performance Tools\x64\vsperfmon" /coverage /output:"C:/inetpub/wwwroot/Service/bin/Test.coverage" /crosssession /user:"everyone"
3. Ran the tests
   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.console.exe" "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Service\bin\ApiTest.dll" /UseVsixExtensions:True /Settings:"XMLFile1.runsettings" /TestCaseFilter:"Name=MyTestCase" /logger:trx /Platform:x64 /inIsolation /enablecodecoverage

TEST RAN SUCCESSFULLY

4. Stopped the monitor
   cd  c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Team Tools\Performance Tools\x64
   vsperfcmd.exe /shutdown